# Primefaces editable dataTable and hibernate validator

Tags: jsf, primefaces, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have an editable dataTable in PrimeFaces and am using the Hibernate Validator for bean validation.  This works fine with a `<p:inputText />` element.  Now I want to have validation on a dataTable which is editable.

This is what is happening:

If I enter valid values, the page updates as expected
If I enter invalid values, when I click the little "save" check mark nothing happens - the cell remains editable, database write is not attempted, no error message is displayed.

There is an `<h:messages />` tag on the page, so why doesn't an error message show up?  The component appears to be aware there was a problem since the row remains in the editable state.

EDIT: I enabled logging and saw this:

```
21:20:43,874 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Adding Message[sourceId=demoTable:j_idt11:2:j_idt15,summary=Testing Hibernate Validator Error Message)
```

So it looks like the context is being correctly updated.  It seems like I need to do something to trigger the message it render.

Comment: In the absence of any example code, this sounds very much like a Hibernate Exception. JSF will skip straight through to Render Response segment which explains why you're getting no Actions and no change in the page navigation. No Validation or Conversion error also explains the lack of FacesMessage for your messages tag. Set a breakpoint and walk it through...

Comment: I enabled logging and saw this:

    21:20:43,874 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Adding Message[sourceId=demoTable:j_idt11:2:j_idt15,summary=Testing Hibernate Validator Error Message)

So it looks like the context is being correctly updated.  It seems like I need to do something to trigger the message it render.

Comment: I also recognized that Primefaces incell editing swallows the messages on failure, which is very annoying since the defined update components are only updated on success. A issue should be filed in primefaces tracker. It even swallows messages like simple `required`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the belowfollowing statement in your jsf file and it should work:

```
<p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"
            closable="true" showSummary="false"/>
```

Comment: <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" showSummary="false"/>